# R pasting individual strings together in specified format

Tags: r

I am trying to get the following individual strings

O U N P D E A Z B X Q R M V H

to look like

"O" & "U" & etc....

This sorta does it... but has the & symbol inside the  quotes like "O&"

```
 paste("",varmap[[temp$SplitVar[2]]],"&",sep="")
```

the varmap part is the O U N P D E A Z B X Q R M V H

the code I was getting it from that someone had written before has it as

```
 for (k in x:0)
      {
       paste("",varmap[[temp$SplitVar[2]]],"&",sep="")
      }
```

but not really sure what the k in x:0 does, and it gives an error of the vector is too long.

Comment: Are you looking for `paste`'s `collapse` argument? `paste(strsplit('O U N P D E A Z B X Q R M V H', ' ')[[1]], collapse = ' & ')`

Comment: well sort of, but I want each string to have quotes around it IE "O" & "U" & "N" vs "O & U & N"

Comment: `paste0('"', strsplit('O U N P D E A Z B X Q R M V H', ' ')[[1]], '"', collapse = ' & ')`, but you'll have to wrap it in `cat` to see it without the quotes escaped by backslashes.

Comment: There is also a function called `dQuote` that could be helpful here